# Why does my Windows Firewall keep forgetting its settings?

Tags: windows, windows-10, firewall

Windows Firewall continually forgets its settings.  It does not remember programs that I allow, and if I turn off notifications for blocked apps, the notifications are turned back shortly (at least after a restart).  It also forgets that I want to block all incoming connections on public networks.

This is on a Windows 10 Pro computer connected to AzureAD. I have not set any group policy settings in either the local group policy editor or through any of AzureAD's settings.  I do have Tunnelbear installed, but it is not running most of the time.

Why does Windows not remember my settings? How can I get it to remember the programs that I have allowed, and remember that I do not want notifications for new blocked programs?

Comment: According to this Reddit thread you can also try to remove TunnelBear.

P.s. sorry for necroposting, but no solution provided here

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you set up your windows firewall rules (e.g. whether you allowed the app to connect on a Domain network, or all types of network), you can get tripped up by the network adapter usage set by the Network Location Awareness service.

If the NLA service decides your adatper is no longer a domain adapter, then any firewall rules that depended on that classification may no longer apply.

Since you're using Azure AD, it could be even more likely that NLA would mis-classify your adapter.

p.s. I would have just posted this as a comment if I had enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and just resolved it in my case. Windows firewall wouldn't remember any settings. If I added a new rule, closed then reopened the firewall advanced settings the rule wouldn't be there. I didn't have any special network settings (e.g. AzureAD) though, just normal home broadband connection.

What I did was go to Control Panel > Internet Options > Security tab > Local internet zone. Unlike the other zones this one didn't have a slider to select security level, it just said something about resetting to default if I wanted to. So click the Default Level button and that brings back the security slider at the Medium-low setting.

This fixed my Windows firewall. No idea how it got in that state.